# How to stop code execute on condition from another controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

my code:

```
public class StateManagementController : Controller
{
    public void OwnerTest()
    {
        if (Session["Owner"] == null)
        {
            Logowanie();
        }            
    }

    public ActionResult Logowanie()
    {            
        return RedirectToAction("Log", "Owner");
    }
}

public class AnimalController : StateManagementController
{
    public ActionResult MyAnimals()
    {
        OwnerTest();
        //some code here
        return View(animals.ToList());
    }
 }
```

The problem is that even if the session is null and Redirect is reached it doesn't redirect me but it still goes to ,,some code" in MyAnimals action, how can I stop it in ActionResult Logowanie? i dont want to change code in MyAnimals, I want only to use function there without checking if it returns something.

Answer (score 0):

You `Logowanie` Action may return an `ActionResult` but the `OwnerTest` method ignores the returned result.  Try this:

```
public class StateManagementController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult OwnerTest()
    {
        if (Session["Owner"] == null)
        {
            return Logowanie();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Logowanie()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Log", "Owner");
    }

public class AnimalController : StateManagementController
{
    public ActionResult MyAnimals()
    {
        var temp = OwnerTest();
        if (temp != null)
        {
            return temp;
        }
        else
        {
            //some code here
            return View(animals.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi :) Thanks for help, it works. But i need to use it in many places in this project, its why i wanted to use it only with function header - "OwnerTest()" to have less copy pasted code. Any advice how to do it?